# Why does Tinder constantly appear on my Opera mobile home page without me adding it?

Tags: browser

I've been using Opera Mobile on my phone for roughly two months now and lately I've noticed that Tinder repeatedly appears on my Opera mobile browser homepage without me adding it.

The first time, I didn't pay it much attention. I thought perhaps I'd clicked on a website that somehow added Tinder on there. I removed it and moved on.

The second time, I got a bit more suspicious, so I reinstalled the app.

Tonight, the third time, my boyfriend saw it and I had to explain to him, in a very awkward and unpleasant conversation, that I'm not actively using Tinder.

Again, I don't and have never used Tinder in any way whatsoever, mobile, desktop, you name it.

This is my homepage right now, with the unwanted Tinder app included:
[image]

Is there a way to completely disable this? I don't want to have to uninstall this browser.

Comment: Turn off suggested sites from settings ; if already turned off then I think nothing more can be done ; and it is present on mine too(have been using it for years but never used tinder)(options are available for turning off promotional speed dials in Opera for PC but not on mobile devices)

Comment: You might want to consider a browser that doesn't do this... Brave Browser would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable promotional speed dials on the mobile browser. The only thing you can do is manually delete them.